# Data table con busca por fecha

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy usando datatable de bootstrap con ajax para que no se demore en la carga, fue la única solución que encontré, pero me surgió otro problema, es que no busca por fecha, todos los otros campos si los busca pero cuando quiero buscar por fecha no busca nada, les dejo mi código donde especifico las búsquedas.
No incluyo el código completo porque es muy grande y la web no me deja

**PORCION DEL CODIGO PHP**

```
if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
$sql = "SELECT id_viaje, fecha_emision, operador, pasajero, salida, regreso ";
    $sql.=" FROM viajes";
//aqui especifico que busco por fecha, por operador por pasajero, salida(fecha), regreso(fecha)
    $sql.=" WHERE fecha_emision LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR fecha_emision LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR operador LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR pasajero LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR salida LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR regreso LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

    $sql .= " ORDER BY ".$columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]." DESC LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");

    
} else {    

    $sql = "SELECT id_viaje, fecha_emision, operador, pasajero, salida, regreso ";
    $sql.=" FROM viajes";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY ".$columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]." DESC LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");

}
```

por operador y pasajero si busca y encuentra pero por fecha nada, alguien sabe a que se debe eso?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: y cual es la parte en donde no hace la busqueda por fecha???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ese es el código, en el campo search ahi se ingresa la fecha y no me trae, pero si yo ingreso operador o pasajero si me traen resultados

Comment: tienes que hacer un debug, valida que contiene el query que estas haciendo cuando envias una fecha... y ese output lo agregas al post editandolo...